# docker image build vs docker build

Tags: docker

Why does my Docker client recognize `docker build` but not `docker image build`? Is the client too old? Does CLI depends on client or server? 
I believe I got my Docker client and server by installing the latest Docker toolbox.

```
$ docker version
Client:
Version:      1.12.5
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.4
Git commit:   7392c3b
Built:        Fri Dec 16 06:14:34 2016
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
Version:      18.01.0-ce
API version:  1.35
Go version:   go1.9.2
Git commit:   03596f5
Built:        Wed Jan 10 20:13:12 2018
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

$ docker image build
docker: 'image' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'.

$ docker build
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s).
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The client version is old. The new commad structure is supported with client 1.13. Check [Docker CLI restructured](https://blog.docker.com/2017/01/whats-new-in-docker-1-13/).

There was a refactoring for the command line client to have the form:

```
docker <management command> <command>
```

The new command structure still supports the old way. For instance, the old `docker ps` is an alias for `docker container ls` and the old `docker build` is alias to `docker image build`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v1.12/engine/reference/commandline/build/) in your client version `docker image build` does not exist yet.

Comment: Documented as being a command in the current CLI here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/ so, yes, it would appear OP needs to upgrade.